# How can I auto-sort by 1 column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to set up my Google Sheets document auto sorts when entering new data.

Link to sheet:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h2-Gy67sTGKdMhG9GP-intB5fVdaJheZIcLo4Nto_Wg/edit?usp=sharing

These are, obviously, player statistics.  I am trying to figure out a solution to have column "H" sort the players in descending order.  Meaning the player with most points will be first.

I've tried using the sort range function to no avail.  I've entered formulas in each cell in column H.  This is just a simple "=SUM(F5:G5)" to total columns F & G.  Could this be what is preventing the page from sorting?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an additional sheet and use the `QUERY` function to generate an auto-sorted view of the data. When you update your main sheet with the data, the sheet using `QUERY` will update as well.

eg. `=QUERY(sheet1!A4:I17, "SELECT * ORDER BY H")`

However, you would want to make your data in sheet1 more regular - eg. instead of using position to separate the goalie from the other players, add another column to store the player type.

Comment: thanks so much for your input.  I have sheet 1 embedded on website so, I would want to embed sheet 2 on the site and just use sheet 1 for updating?  And,as far as the position type goes, are you saying to move the goalie with the skaters?  If you would, clarify that a little more, I would appreciate it.  Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: Hi David – Yep, just like you write, use sheet 1 for data and sheet 2 embedding. As for putting the goalie with the skaters, you'd need to do something like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eIX55pOqzYuK7WqrHK4AiG4I7CH4QBWeQ8TCodd-9NM/edit . The advantage of this kind of pattern is that you can easily add other columns (team, start date, end date, ...) and have a simple database of players and stats that you use `QUERY` to display.

Comment: thanks very much for your assistance.  I think I got it.

Comment: No worries. Good luck! :)